# visual studio source stepping

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

not sure what else to try, but i am not able to step through the .net source code.

In the debugging options

1. Enable just my code is unchecked.
2. enable source server support is checked.
3. Enable source server support is checked.

In the debugging symbols 
1. Microsoft symbol servers is checked.
2. cache symbol directory is set.

when i try to step through some system.servicemodel.dll stack trace,

in the modules windows, i can right click and load symbols for servicemodel dll
it flashes the cancel dialog, like its doing something
the stack becomes black from grayed out
but when i click on the method it shows no source code available

any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Visual Studio could not find the appropriate code for your DLL. Perhaps the easiest way is to re-build the DLL, and reference the DLL with the code in the expected directory. Let's try that first, and see what we can learn from your testing.

Comment: Is there a mixture of .NET Framework versions? If the versions are different, then that might confuse the Studio, I suspect.